# How long does it typically take to apply for EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I applied for an amazon web services account the other day, and most of the services have been provisioned for me and are available to use. The one I want to use however, is EC2, and it is stuck on the account page with the message:

```
Authorizing your account to access this web service
```

Is it normal to take this long to get EC2 access? It's been about 24 hours. If this is not normal, what avenues do I have in order to rectify the situation?

Comment: Did you receive the phone call from them for that service?  It usually comes over in ~15 minutes after signup.

Comment: I did. In the end it took about 48 hours for it to be provisioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd. My account was activated in minutes. Give their [support](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/aws-account-and-billing) a try.